# Argus Camera DC-1512E will not transfer photos

Tags: 11.10, usb, shotwell, camera

I can't transfer photos from this camera. It will not show up a drive. Shotwell does not acknowledge it's existence. lsusb reports the camera as "Primax Elecrtonics". Help?

Comment: Some digital cameras need you to switch to "mass storage mode" - you need to have a look through the menus for such an option.

Comment: This was a ten dollar camera in it's time and is probanly worth 30 cents now. It doesn't have a screen, just some leds. I want to get it working so my younger brother can take pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shotwell's digital camera support comes from GPhoto.  A list of supported cameras is here:

http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php

Since your camera isn't on the list, it may not be supported; though since there's a couple similar model numbers mentioned I'd still think it ought to work.

You might try asking on the GPhoto mailing list if there's any known issues with that camera.