# Cannot transfer digital photos from HP Photosmart Camera

Tags: hp, shotwell

I connected the camera via USB and it was promptly recognized by Ubuntu and Shotwell, however when attempting to import photos, Shotwell can only find a single photo among hundreds. When accessing the camera via Nautilus, I can see the folders and all photos there but they are all greyed, not accessible and I am unable to find a way to transfer them.

I've been [here](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php) and my camera is not present, however some others quite similar are listed. Also I've been at HP support and the drivers for download are available for Windows and Mac only. I do know that I can transfer the photos on Windows using Windows Photo Gallery and I did not need to install additional drivers to do it, so I was expecting Ubuntu could do the same.

I'm not sure if it is an issue with Shotwell not supporting the camera, missing drivers or something else, because it is a bit strange that it can find a single photo instead of not finding anything at all, which is why I decided to ask this question, despite knowing that there are similar questions (such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76154/argus-camera-dc-1512e-will-not-transfer-photos) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143358/unable-to-import-digital-photos)) about this topic, however all of them report *completely* unsuccessful transfer attempts

Is there any way to make shotwell transfer the photos? If not, any other application that might do it successfully?

Comment: What file type are the images, JPEG? Also, assuming the camera saves to a memory card of some type, have you tried pulling the card out and using a USB card reader?

Comment: Yes, they are .JPG images. Well I don't have a USB card reader, it would be good to have another kind of option because I prefer to just boot into Windows and make the transfer rather than buying something additional...

Comment: Which camera model is it?  Also, some of HP's cameras have a setting in the on-screen menu to toggle between "camera" and "disk" mode.  Does yours have this option?  If so, what is it set to?

Comment: My answer here might help- it is for a different model but the answer should apply: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173811/kodak-easy-share-c195-camera-mounting/184539#184539