# Access to USB devices not working properly

Tags: 12.04, camera

Why can I no longer see the photos on my camera card after upgrading to 12.04 (64 bit)?
In 10.04 LTS I could read the camera card and import photos happily.  Now, under 12.04 LTS (64 bit) I can access the card in the camera and see the various folders, but cannot see the image files, nor can I import them to the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two main options here:

1) The first solution is that perhaps your camera isn't properly mounted; you can actually browse the files in the `.gvfs` folder in your home folder if it has been mounted correctly (you will need to check *show hidden files* in your file browser).

The location of the gvfs folder for Ubuntu 12.10 and beyond is now: `/run/user/username/gvfs`.

See also my other answer below where I go into more details about manually mounting a camera (it is actually not model specific so may be very useful for you):

- [Can't transfer photos from Kodak Easy Share C195 Camera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173811/kodak-easy-share-c195-camera-mounting)

2) Take the memory card out and use a card-reader to access the files and use software that is specifically designed for that purpose and can import your photos into a meaningful directory structure. I have used `rapid-photo-downloader` before; it is available in the repositories and the [official site](http://www.damonlynch.net/rapid/) contains detailed information on the program.