# How do I get a Samsung ES 73 Camera working?

Tags: 12.04, samsung, camera

I am using a [Samsung ES73](http://www.samsung.com/latin_en/consumer/cameras-camcorders/cameras/compact/EC-ES73ZZBPOPA-spec) Digital Camera.

I am looking to use this camera on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Please guide, how any software can help me transfer or view photos from this camera?

Please guide, any device driver which can help me detect this camera.

Answer (score 1):

After digital cameras are connected to the USB port and switched on, they are normally automatically mounted and made available to the filebrowser by `libgphoto2`, and even though your model is not on the [compatibility list](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php), it will probably still work. Searching the [mailing lists](http://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=8874) is also a good way of finding possible compatibility issues with your particular model.

After reading [the official manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201003/20100315185104531/ES73_ES74_English.pdf) for your camera, there does seem to be some other settings *on the camera itself*, which will allow you to specify how it connects to your computer. The screenshot below shows these settings: in *automatic* mode it will be recognised in Ubuntu as a PTP device (by `libgphoto`) and in *computer* mode as a USB mass storage device. In this latter mode your camera is recognised just like a flash drive, and the `gphoto` libraries are not used when it is mounted this way. It is worth experimenting with these modes, and there is more information on them in the [useful gphoto FAQ](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/manual/FAQ.html).

[image]

**However**, if you are still having problems, it may be possible to mount the camera using `gvfs-mount`. I go through that whole process in detail in another answer. It is about a different model of camera, but the instructions will be the same:

- [Can't transfer photos from Kodak Easy Share C195 Camera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173811/kodak-easy-share-c195-camera-mounting)

In that answer I also mention software such as `gthumb` and `shotwell`, which can be used to import your photos.