# Photo transfer problems from camera

Tags: usb, files, camera, photo

We have a digital camera (Cannon SX130 IS) which we often connect to the Ubuntu 12.10 desktop via USB in order to download the images.  In past flavours of Linux (Mint 12 was most recent) it worked fine, however since upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10, the process fails after downloading a small number of the images.  I can view the images which will be transferred in the preview window, and I can browse the camera file system to download the images manually,  but if I just drag/drop the images over from camera to desktop, it freezes after 5-6 are copied over.

I've been able to get around the problem by only copying 3-4 at a time, but when you have 100+ images to transfer, that gets really frustrating.

Any advice on where I could start looking for answers, or how I could diagnose the source of the problem further?  We have also had some issues with WireLess USB mice though it may not be related.

I'm hoping my USB controller in the computer isn't dying... it's not that old.  Also, it seems to work much better under Windows.

Comment: My answer here might help: it concerns a different model, but the general instructions are still valid: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173811/kodak-easy-share-c195-camera-mounting

Comment: I am having similar issues but with copying files over SMB from my NAS. I researched some more and it seems the current version of gvfs cannot handle too much data (in my case copying hangs after a few hundred megabytes). I also noticed this was logged as a bug but the latest update I saw was that they are in need for a SMB/gvfs expert to fix this. See this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1075923

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in Ubuntu 12.10 too, copying photographs from USB camera to local disk. The copy progress hangs and does nothing. Though I haven't had a fix for this but importing the photos using Shotwell Photo Manager did help. I could copy all the photos to local disk.

Try Shotwell, it might help you.