# What is the default method / program to download photos from a photo camera to the computer?

Tags: xubuntu, canon, camera, thunar, photo-management

I am in Xubuntu 12.10 and Thunar doesn't access the camera memory (Canon) so as to just copy/paste the pictures.

I want to import the pictures onto the PC.

I heard about F-spot and [rapid-photo-downloader](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/rapid-photo-downloader) - but what I read on them were rather old articles. Are they the thing?

Comment: [In this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/173811/cant-transfer-photos-from-kodak-easy-share-c195-camera/184539#184539) I discuss a few useful things. Maybe you can modify the script from that answer and get your camera to mount using `gvfs-mount` on `gphoto2://` and then it should be available in Thunar.

Comment: I find interesting all the answer, especially the script and the idea of using Shotwell. The script would be more useful for a specific camera, Shotwell for dealing with any cameras. I'll edit and even maybe create an answer linked to yours, if this is suitable, as soon as I have the opportunity to test these solutions.

Comment: `gthumb` also has a useful import facility, but I should see which options listed in the linked answer are best for you.

Comment: @Mik - is there a specific command to import pictures with **gthumb**? just seeing them in gthumb, selecting them and right-click "copy to..." would stuck the program during the processing of the first picture (in the case of the Canon I was testing with). **Rapid Photo Downloader** is affected by a bug so I left it out of this. **Shotwell** worked perfectly and I have created an answer for it

Comment: Yes, in gthumb > file > import from > removable device. Shotwell works fine though, as you demonstrate.

Comment: @Mik - even so, for some reason that I'll not further investigate here,  gthumb has the same problem with that camera, so that I cannot add it to the answer, but maybe I'll reedit in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is the result of info provided by [Mik](https://askubuntu.com/users/76204/mik) in a comment, indicating [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/184539/47206) of his.

---

[Shotwell [image: Install Shotwell]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shotwell/)does very well what is asked.

Just connect the camera and start it (without mounting it), and run Shotwell . It will try to access the pictures.

[image]

In this way the camera contents are visible. Selecting some or all of them you can then right-click import them into ~/Pictures/Year/Month_etc/

[image]

After that the program will offer to delete the pictures on the camera.

[image]

Pictures are stored in multiple directory levels, according to year, month, day, but this is customizable - under 'Edit/Preferences' - Importing: Directory structure.

[image]