# How can I mount a Samsung Camera on Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, mount, camera

So I have been trying to mount my Samsung 3150f camera and I have been using a combination of these two tutorials:

- [Detect and mount devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285539/detect-and-mount-devices)
- [Can't transfer photos from Kodak Easy Share C195 Camera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173811/cant-transfer-photos-from-kodak-easy-share-c195-camera)

but when I enter `lsusb` I get this:

```
*-usb
    description: Mass storage device
    product: Samsung Digital Camera
    vendor: FUJITSU
    physical id: 1
    bus info: usb@3:1
    logical name: scsi8
    version: 0.00
    serial: E00000000002
    capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
    configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=100mA spe`
```

The second link has been really helpful but is telling me I should be looking for something like:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 040a:0565 Kodak, Inc.
```

I see the Bus info but the other two I am not sure if they are called something else? Or am I totally on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1):

Why should a tutorial about a Kodak camera give you a string to search for in a Samsung camera? Never mind. See `product: Samsung Digital Camera`

One interesting line is:

```
configuration: driver=usb-storage
```

which tells you that your Samsung camera looks like a `usb-storage` device (mountable disk).

Record the time (`touch /tmp/now` or write it down). Unplug your camera from your system, wait 10 seconds, reconnect your camera, wait another 10 seconds, and type `dmesg -T` in a terminal window. Look at the entries with times later than the time you recorded (`ls -l /tmp/now`). They will show you what the system thinks is going on when you connect your camera. One piece of information to look for is the device name (`sda`, `sdb`, `sdc`, etc), which will be useful in the `mount` command, if necessary (`man -a mount`).

With the camera connected, use `mount` to see what is mounted, `df` to look at the space and where it is mounted, IF it auto-mounted.

Once you know the device name, you need to find out the partition type.  Type:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and look for your device name.

Now that you know the device name and the filesystem type (also known as `fstype`), read `man mount`, a couple of times.

Comment: This is what I get when I type `dmesg -T`

Comment: Actually the response is too long to paste here, but I do see where it detects it. There is a red font that states `[sdb] No Caching mode page found` and right below it says `[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through`     would that mean anything significant?  Sorry if I am asking dumb questions, still a newb.

Comment: It looks like my camera is labeled as sdb1